# Python getattr callable function

Tags: python, python-3.x

I have the following:

```
instance = Service.objects.get(pk=1)
attr = "members.all"
t = functools.reduce(getattr, attr.split("."), instance)()
print(t)
```

It evaluates to `instance.members.all()`

Using Python 3.x how can I evaluate the following using the same methodology?

```
attr = "members.filter(gender='Male')"
```

To evaluate to `instance.members.filter(gender='Male')`

Comment: Not without a great deal of pain. Why do you want to do this? Where is the string coming from? There is probably a better way of doing it (in other words, this is an [XY problem](http://xyproblem.info/)).

Comment: @DanielRoseman My usecase: When saving any model I need a list of users, each model has a different set of users which can change. I used to pass the users as an ``queryset``, but now I'm using a broker and this is done on another machine  so I now need each model to simply tell me how to query the db to get their users base.

Comment: Is there a limited set of queries? You might consider making a series of methods on the model, or on the manager.

Comment: I check each model has ``if getattr(instance, notify_users, None):`` on a ``post_save`` function. If so I pass the string of that model method i.e. ``members.all`` to a task. This task gets run later. Their are many different lookups needed which can change. My problem is now some  models want to restrict the query i.e. ``members.al(activate=True)`` so my task needs to account for this.

Comment: It seems like it might be cleaner to send a method name plus a dictionary of arguments, rather than sending the string of Python code.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You should *parse* the expression and work with the syntax tree to resolve this. The following is an incomplete example that works with your sample expression. You can expand it to support more syntax constructs:

```
import ast
def evaluate (expr, ref):
    if isinstance(expr, ast.Module):
        return evaluate(expr.body[0], ref)
    elif isinstance(expr, ast.Expr):
        return evaluate(expr.value, ref)
    elif isinstance(expr, ast.Call):
        args = [evaluate(x, ref) for x in expr.args]
        kwargs = {kw.arg: evaluate(kw.value, ref) for kw in expr.keywords}
        return evaluate(expr.func, ref)(*args, **kwargs)
    elif isinstance(expr, ast.Attribute):
        return getattr(evaluate(expr.value, ref), expr.attr)
    elif isinstance(expr, (ast.Str, ast.Num)):
        return ast.literal_eval(expr)

    # special case; look up names on the reference object
    elif isinstance(expr, ast.Name):
        return getattr(ref, expr.id)
    else:
        print('Unknown type', type(expr))
```

You can use it like this:

```
expr = "members.filter(gender='Male')"
evaluate(ast.parse(expr), referenceObject)
```

As an example, I have created the following dummy object:

```
>>> def debug (*args, **kwargs):
        print(args, kwargs)

>>> from types import SimpleNamespace
>>> ref = SimpleNamespace()
>>> ref.members = SimpleNamespace()
>>> ref.members.filter = debug
>>> evaluate(ast.parse("members.filter(gender='Male')"), ref)
() {'gender': 'Male'}
```

Comment: Sorry I've not seen evaluate do you mean eval?

Comment: No, `evaluate` is a function I defined in my answer. Using `eval` (or `exec`) is bad as it can execute arbitrary code without any control, whereas with a custom function like this `evaluate`, you have full control over what operations you allow and how to execute them.

Comment: Ok, sorry I think I have to just wrap my head around your code a little more I got confused at you returning ``evaluate(expr.value, ref)`` i.e itself.

Comment: It’s a recursive function that evaluates the expression tree returned by `ast.parse`. It basically starts at the top and then cascades down in the tree, starts evaluating that, and then constructs the result value on the way back up.

Comment: Can I just say this is actually a really clever idea!

Comment: I’m glad you like it :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is one possible approach, using `exec()`:

```
class Members():
    def filter(self, gender):
        print("Gender is", gender)

class Foo():
    def __init__(self):
        self.members = Members()

>>> instance = Foo()
>>> exec("members.filter(gender='Male')", instance.__dict__)
Gender is Male
```

Keep in mind that it can be dangerous to use `exec` with unvalidated input, but there are places where it can be useful.

Edit – some additional explanation:

- When you call `exec`, you pass a dictionary that gives the context or namespace in which the code will be executed. Above I pass `instance.__dict__` so that the code will be executed in this namespace: i.e. the namespace where `members` exists
- Using `exec` in Python can be dangerous if the string comes from an unknown source: it means you're executing arbitrary (and potentially malicious) code. This is one reason it's often recommended not to use it; however there are some places where it's used effectively: the NamedTuple implementation in Python's standard library comes to mind.

Comment: Interesting, in this example why would this be  dangerous? also why ``.__dict__``?